# How can I use a terminal software like PuTTY to login to a DOS PC that functions as a Host via serial connection?

Tags: terminal, putty, com-port

I have connected my client PC and a little DOS PC via serial cable and used PuTTY to establish a connection between the two.

I did a simple test by typing `echo hello>com1` into the command line of the DOS PC. And the message appeared in the PuTTY terminal window.

My real goal is to command the DOS PC via the PuTTY terminal, like it's also possible with Linux machines. But it doesn't seem to work this way. I think I am missing something here. Does it have something to do with protocols or is there software missing on the DOS PC?

I hope someone can help me out here?

Comment: I know it's not exactly the question but I recon other people might come in here for a tangential reason: IF what you're trying to do is copy files off of an old DOS system, there are the [intersvr and interlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DOS_commands#INTERSVR_and_INTERLNK) builtin serial- or parallel port client/server tools.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I solved it myself. I found a DOS tool called [WHOST](http://josh.com/WHOST/). The key components are three files. `setbaud.exe`, `go.bat` and `host.bat`. The client PC and the host PC both need all of those files.

1. Connect both PCs with a serial cable, then turn on the PCs.
2. On the host pc, navigate to the folder containing the WHOST files. Then type `setbaud 3F8 38`. `3F8` is the adress of the serial Port in HEX aka COM1. `38` is the short form of 38,400 baud. It is the data transfer speed. It has to be the same on both PCs, otherwise the data won't be interpreted correctly.
3. Type `host` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. Now the host PC is ready for the remote connection.
4. On the client PC type `setbaud` with the same parameters as on the host PC.
5. Type `go` into the console and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. The program will ask for a password. It's `foobar` by default. After pressing enter for one last time, the connection should be established. You can now control the host PC via your client PC as if you where directly sitting in front of it.

**If you want to terminate the connection**: Type `exit` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. The connection will be terminated. The only catch is that in order to establish a new connection you have to start `host.bat` again on the host PC. Otherwise it won't work because WHOST won't be listening on the configured COM port any longer… I assume.

I've set up a DOS VirtualBox machine as a client. It works like a charm.

Comment: Really good answer!

Comment: SETBAUD seems like it just does what the built-in `MODE COM1' ...` could do as well...

Answer (score 1):

*Apologies in advance - not the best answer ever, but I'm curios - I really can not remember because it was decades ago since last time I needed to do something like this. Have fun experimenting! :-)*

Isn't there a way to achieve the same thing by, on the "server" side, setting the serial port params using `MODE` then launching `COMMAND.COM COM1` or `CTTY COM`? Then just open the terminal on the "client" side with identical mode params.